# Json Iterating using java

Tags: java, json, getjson

Here is my json Object.

```
{"id":"mrbbt6f3fa99gld0m6n52osge0",
 "name_value_list":
 {"user_default_dateformat":{"name":"user_default_dateformat","value":"m/d/Y"}},
 "module_name":"Users"}
```

I got id,and module_name through following code.How can i get user_default_dateformat?.

I know it may so simple but I am a newbie in json.

```
        String jsonResponse;

        while ((jsonResponse = br.readLine()) != null) {

            jsonOutput = jsonResponse;

        }
        JSONObject job = new JSONObject(jsonOutput);

        System.out.println(job);// i can see the same json object 
                                                that i showen above.
        sessionID = job.get("id").toString();
```

Exception generating coge

```
JSONObject job2=new JSONObject(job);
dateFormat = job2.get("user_default_dateformat").toString();
```

The Eexception is

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["user_default_dateformat"] not found.
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

name_value_list is also an Object.

```
JSONObject job2 = new JSONObject(job.get("name_value_list"));
```

So there you get

```
job2.get("user_default_dateformat");
```

Every {} in your JSON is an object. So for every String you get which is something like `{"xy":"za","ab":"cd"}` you have to cast it to the JSONObject

**Edit for your error:**

As you can see in your code the line:

```
JSONObject job2=new JSONObject(job);
```

will try to generate a JSONObject out of your JSONObject.

You have to get the JSONObject **in** your JSONObject.

You want to get the user_default_dateformat which is in your JSONObject:

```
String name_value_list_string = job.get("name_value_list").toString();
//this string is another json-string which contains the user_default_dateformat
JSONObject name_value_list_object = new JSONObject(name_value_list_string);

//This JSONObject contains the user_default_dateformat but this is also a JSONObject

String user_default_dateformat_string = name_value_list_object.get("user_default_dateformat").toString();
//this String contains the user_default_dateformat JSONString

JSONObject user_default_dateformat_object = new JSONObject(user_default_dateformat_string);

//This JSONObject contains the String values of your user_default_dateformat
```

Comment: Thank you Loki..but i got the same execption..org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["user_number_seperator"] not found.

Comment: Can you post your code? Maybe I can see what your problem is. Just edit your Question and add your code.

Comment: Where did "user_number_seperator" come from? Are you trying to get a JSON property that's not in the JSON object?

Comment: So where is your problem? What does the stacktrace say? In what line occurc what error?

Comment: I got id with out any problem..but while am trying user_currency_name,i got this execption:org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["user_default_dateformat"] not found.

Comment: Can you post your whole code please. With the lines that cause the error. All you did is showing us the code that works.

Comment: Did you understand my example?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using JSONSimple library you can use this:

jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(jsonstr);
      System.out.println((JSONObject)jsonObject.get("name_value_list"))).get("user_default_dateformat"));

This should give you the required result.